# Binary Search stuck in infinite loop

Tags: ruby

I am trying to test a binary search algorithm. The logic seems right, however, I'm running into some issues.

There are two different methods, `case` and `if`.  If one method fails, the other is right.

1.

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

def search(arr, value)
  if arr.nil?
    return "value not in array"
  end
  l = 0
  u = (arr.length - 1)
  t = value
  if l > u
    puts "array is wrong!"
    return
  end

  while l < u
    m = (l + u) / 2
    case m
    when m < t
      l = (m + 1)
    when m == t
      puts "hello world"
    when m > t
      u = (m - 1)
    end
  end
end


search(arr, 5)
```

2.

```
def search(arr, value)
  if arr.nil?
    return "value not in array"
  end
  l = 0
  u = (arr.length - 1)
  t = value
  if l > u
    puts "array is wrong!"
    return
  end

  while l < u
    m = (l + u) / 2
    if m < t
      l = (m + 1)
    elsif m == t
      puts "hello world"
      break
    elsif m > t
      u = (m - 1)
    end
  end
end
```

I thought my code would work, but something is causing my while loop to go on infinitely. What am I doing to cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Print `l` and `u` at the start of the loop, see where you get stuck.

Comment: this is show `l = 0`, `u = 9`

Comment: Replace `case m` with simply `case`.

Comment: oh, haha , it's happened `hello world`